# Listening to non-verbose log entries only with enterprise library

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I'm marking verbose log entries like this:

```
Logger.Write(new LogEntry 
{ 
    Message = "Using debug quote id...", 
    Severity = TraceEventType.Verbose 
});
```

How do I configure enterprise library event listener to log non-verbose events only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your trace switch to only listen for Warning or Error level events.  You can do this in your application .config file.

Check out [this article](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020910.htm) or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t06xyy08(VS.80).aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: One more quick question. How do I temporarily disable listener. Remove it from within source?

Comment: You should be able to set the TraceLevel to 0 (None).  Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3at424ac(VS.80).aspx.